# Want .focus() attributes to remain when clicking out of a div

Tags: jquery, html

This is the code i am using to operate a tab function.

```
   <div id="tabs">
        <ul class="ulclass">
            <li><a href="#fragment-1" class="button button1"><span>AFFILIATE INFORMATION</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-2" class="button"><span>RESELLING</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-3" class="button"><span>TERMS AND CONDITIONS</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="fragment-1" class="tabtext">
        </div>
        <div id="fragment-2" class="tabtext">
        </div>
        <div id="fragment-3" class="tabtext">
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
   $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
</script>
```

My js to keep the focus effect on on page load is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('.button1').focus();
});
```

this is just a background of white to show the selected tab but when i click anywhere but the other tab links (including in the div related to the tab)the focus effect (white) drops off and you can't tell which tab you are on.

Could someone please help me with some jquery to get the focus effect to only remove when the other tabs are clicked on? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<div class="tab_container">
    <a target="1" class="select">Personal</a>
    <a target="2">Experience</a>
    <a target="3">Education</a>
</div>
<div id="div1" class="tab_link" style="display:block;">
    Personal Details Comes here
</div>
<div id="div2" class="tab_link" style="display:none;">
    Experience Details Comes here
</div>
<div id="div3" class="tab_link" style="display:none;">
    Education Details Comes here
</div>
```

CSS :

```
*{margin:0; padding:0; font-family:Tahoma; font-size:12px; color:#333;}
.tab_container{margin:10px; margin-bottom:0;}
.tab_container a{display:inline-block; padding:0 10px; line-height:25px; background:#eee;    border:1px solid #ddd; cursor:pointer;}
.tab_container a.select{background:#fff;}
.tab_link{padding:10px; border:1px solid #ddd; margin:0 10px;}
```

Javascript :

```
$('.tab_container a').click(function () {
    $('.tab_link').hide();
    $('.tab_container a').removeClass('select');
    $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).fadeIn();
    $(this).addClass('select');
});
```

Make sure to include JQuery also from [JQuery.com](http://www.jquery.com)

Comment: Tried this with no luck sorry. will have to try have a play around with the css of the content i think, they dont switch over, only the first one shows then when i click through the tabs nothing shows after that

Comment: Joke just got it to work haha, 2 seconds after saying that! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`.focus()` focuses the selected element, allowing your CSS to match `:focus`, there is no way to focus multiple elements and you do not want to prevent the user from focusing anything else on your page. Use an `active` or `selected` class and the `addClass` method.

Comment: Yes i tried that first, using addClass, you would think it was simple but i just couldn't get it working!

Comment: Using addClass is the way to go, if you encounter any problems search google, read the docs, and then if the problem remains create a new qustion. Its not that hard. Instead of writing `.focus()` you write `.addClass("active")` and change your `:focus` matcher inside the css to `.active`.